# Dropdown not getting selected

Tags: selenium, dropdown, selenium3

I am working on selenium 3, and iI am having an issue to cater for dropdown....Is there a solution for selenium 3 to select from a dropdown?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
     String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com";
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.get(baseUrl);

     driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("rubric2016");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("rubric2016");

     driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

     Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name(“fromMonth"))); 
     dropdown.selectByVisibleText(“March");


 }
}
```

When I execute above code, dropdown is not getting selected?

Comment: Please share Html code of select

Comment: Can you provide us the following information: 1. What is your objective? 2. What do you mean by cater to Dropdown? 3. Is it a normal Dropdown or a modal Dropdown? 4. Which value do you want to select?

Comment: Additionally provide the HTML DOM & snapshot of the Dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

Put some `wait` after click on `login button`. For wait I have used `explicit wait` method.

For example, from dropdown I want to select `April` month and I have used `xpath` locator to find the `dropdown element`.

I have use `relative xpath` method here to locate the dropdown element.

If you want to select another month from dropdown, then simply changed the `selectByVisibleText("Your Month");`

```
driver.get("http://newtours.demoaut.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("rubric2016");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("rubric2016");

driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/table/tbody/..//select[@name='fromMonth']"))));
new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/table/tbody/..//select[@name='fromMonth']"))).selectByVisibleText("April");
```

Comment: If this my answer is `helpful` to you, then please mark this answer as `Accepted`